# TinyMCE - fullscreen mode find calling editor

Tags: tinymce

I have multiple tinyMCE editors on one page, I'm using :

```
   setup : function(ed) {
      ed.onKeyPress.add(function(ed, e) {
          //do stuff with ed.id
      });
   }
```

This registers the event regardless of whether I'm in fullscreen mode or not, which is what I want.

However, ed.id appears to be different depending on whether fullscreen mode is active or not. What I'm wondering is how can I get a reference to the *CALLING* tinyMCE editor when this keypress event is running.

For example,

on keypress Editor id = "TinyMCE_editor1" - click on fullscreen mode , and ed.id = "mce_fullscreen". I'd like a reference to "TinyMCE_editor1".

Currently, I can't adequately traverse to the correct position in the DOM to perform what I need, without a reference to the tinyMCE editor which opened the "fullscreen mode" editor.

Any ideas / help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the param "fullscreen_editor_id" passed to the plugin,
then to detect if you are in full screen or not you can use the OR operator (as shown below).

```
setup : function(ed) {
    ed.onKeyPress.add(function(ed, e) {
        var editorId = ed.getParam("fullscreen_editor_id") || ed.id;
        // Do your stuff
    });
},
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Why I'm downvoted? the editorId variable holds the correct TinyMCE identifier, from there it's easy to move forward and get the object reference.